# How to choose predictors to forecast?

Tags: forecasting

I have a data sheet includes 66 variables. And explanation variable is seasonal. How to choose the predictors and which model to use? Is there any basic steps?

Comment: What you are asking about is a "branch" of statistics called model variable selection and it's much too expansive to explain in a single post -- there are entire courses on it.  I typically like to chose which variables to include in my models based on theory and prior research.  You should start there but also search the Cross-Validated archives for variable selection and see what comes up.  I'd also recommend performing a Google search on "Variable Selection" and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

In the hope of giving you something other than just a "go and read a book" answer. Assuming that you are using [R] there are a bunch of useful automated feature selection libraries.

- Boruta. TLDR; Uses Random Forests and predictor randomization to determine importance. Best place to get your head around it is the JStatSoft paper: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i11/v36i11.pdf and for an excellent worked example try this Kaggle script. https://www.kaggle.com/jimthompson/bnp-paribas-cardif-claims-management/using-the-boruta-package-to-determine-fe
- Max Kuhn's Caret package has a bunch of useful  tools including wrapping several algorithm with feature selection or at least ranking capability. http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html

  - VarSelRF provides both forward and backward elimination and importance rank filtering. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/varSelRF/index.html

HTH

Comment: Please mark as answer.